# Cannot build iOS App on Xcode after upgrade to RN 0.66 and Xcode 13 'gtest/gtest.h' file not found

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, googletest

After upgrading RN from 0.61.5 to 0.66 and updating Xcode from 12 to 13 I am unable to build the iOS App.

My pod file is:

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

target 'strongauthappreact' do
  # Pods for strongauthappreact
  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  # pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/React/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
  pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'

  pod 'boost', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/boost.podspec'
  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  # pod 'ReactCommon/jscallinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'React-callinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/callinvoker"
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  # pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'
  pod 'RCT-Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec'
  pod 'React-perflogger', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/reactperflogger'
  pod 'React-logger', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/logger'

  pod 'React-runtimeexecutor', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/runtimeexecutor'

  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
  pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera.podspec"

  pod 'RNI18n', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-i18n'

  pod 'react-native-randombytes', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-randombytes'

  pod 'jail-monkey', :path => '../node_modules/jail-monkey'

  pod 'react-native-config', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-config'

  pod 'react-native-splash-screen', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-splash-screen'

  pod 'RNExitApp', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-exit-app'

  pod 'react-native-sqlite-storage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-sqlite-storage'

  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'
  
  pod 'TrustKit'

  pod 'Folly-GTest', '~> 1.10'

  pod 'RNCAsyncStorage', :path => '../node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage'

  use_native_modules!
end
```

The error I get is:

> 'gtest/gtest.h' file not found

from there:

[image]

I tried reset metro cache, cleaning $TMPDIR, rm node_modules, rm Pods, reinstall all, clean build cache from Xcode, but I am still stuck here.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Any findings on this? Have same issue

Answer (score 3):

Try to replace

```
pod 'React-perflogger', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/reactperflogger'
pod 'React-logger', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/logger'
pod 'React-runtimeexecutor', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/runtimeexecutor'
```

with

```
pod 'React-perflogger', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/reactperflogger'
pod 'React-logger', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/logger'
pod 'React-runtimeexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/runtimeexecutor'
```

and reinstall pods. It helped me.